# How to send POST request from xmlhttp object after some sleep

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

I want to send some `POST` request from `xmlhttp` object using `javascript` without waiting for the response after some sleep. Inside a `for` loop, this request is being sent. If i am sending all the request without waiting, my browser becomes not responding for a while also it is not allowed from the server side. How can i put sleep among all these `POST` request?
This is what i am using-

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //set args here, which is based elements of array users
    http.open('POST', '/user/home/index.php', true);
    //Set all headers here then send the request
    http.send(args);
}
```

Comment: Also can you add some code to show us what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Amitd: yup. sure... see the edited question. it wasn't possible to put the entire code.. so the main part i have kept here

Comment: @Amitd — Please don't point people towards W3Schools. That page is particularly bad as it starts out by giving an example that uses a string as the first argument but never explains that syntax or why it shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to delay current script execution. You'll have to use async request and restructure your code.

So if you have your code like this:

```
function postData() {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //set args here, which is based elements of array users
        http.open('POST', '/user/home/index.php', true);
        //Set all headers here then send the request
        http.send(args);
        //access request result
        if (http.status == 200) {
            console.log(http.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log('request error');
        }
    }
}
```

Change it like this:

```
var userIndex = 0;

function postData() {
    if (userIndex >= users.length) {
        //no more users to process
        return;
    }

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //set args here, which is based elements of array users
    http.open('POST', '/user/home/index.php', true);

    //set request handler
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (http.readyState != 4) return;
        if (http.status == 200) {
            console.log(http.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log('request error');
        }
        //process next user index
        userIndex++;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            postData(); //do it again
        }, 5000); //5 seconds delay
    };

    //Set all headers here then send the request
    http.send(args);
}

postData(); //start the request chain
```

Comment: Tell me if i am wrong anywhere `Before sending request to the server you are doing state check and logging the response` Right?
I am using `async Request` already but my server doesn't allow request in this faster rate. There must be some interval ~m.s. among all the request.

Comment: @RaviJoshi: Updated code for that case.

Comment: function `window.setTimeout` needs modification. see [this]( http://stackoverflow.com/a/3583740/1175065)